# python with statement and 2 for loops

Tags: python

Format of fname is just single lines of text:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        line_count += 1
    for line in f:
        line_processed += 1
```

I am trying to iterate once through the list to get a total line count first. I then iterate over the text again to process each of the strings. The first for loop is executed while the second is not. Why does this occur? Is there a better way to go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: why do u want to loop many times for just count. see my answer u get it right away

Comment: Why not do it in one pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `f.seek(0)` to set the file's current position

Example:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        line_count += 1
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        line_processed += 1
```

But I think you should store lines in a variable then use for loop instead of loop through `f`:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    line_count = len(lines)
    for line in lines:
        line_processed += 1
```

Comment: @workandcreate this is like reading total file to bottom and again going top and looping again.cant we acheive both requirement in oneloop

Comment: u can use enumerate. no need of line processed to...

Answer (score 2):

It occurs because the first for loop iterates to the end of file. The second for loop has nothing left to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(fname) as f:
    linecount=len(f.readlines())

    for lineno,line in enumerate(f):
        #lineno give each line no .for proccesd
```

enumerate- gives u index of line and the line value so no need of declaring line processed

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in f:
   line_count += 1
```

For each iteration, python calls `f.next()` which returns the next line until the end of the file. Now on the second for loop, `f.next()` is called again but you simply receive the end of the file again, which is why it doesn't do anything anymore. You can call

```
f.seek(0)
```

to reset the file cursor to the beginning of the file, or just use two `with` statements.